# Que veut dire « lui » dans la chanson « À la claire fontaine »?

Tags: sens, québec, paroles-de-chanson

J'ai reçu de ma grand-maman une copie du recueil [« Chansons populaires de Canada »](https://archive.org/details/chansonspopulair00gagnuoft) qui a été compilé par Ernest Gagnon. À l'intérieur on trouve les paroles de la chanson « Claire Fontaine » (pages 2 et 3) comme suit:

```
À la claire fontaine
M'en allant promener,
J'ai trouvé l'eau si belle
Que je m'y suis baigné.
  Lui ya longtemps que je t'aime
  Jamais je ne t'oublierai.
```

Que signifie le mot « lui » dans ce contexte-ci? J'ai cherché dans le [TFLi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lui) et les seuls sens donnés semblent être les biens connus, c'ést-à-dire les cas particuliers des pronoms personnels de la troisième personne du singulier sous la forme d'un complément indirect.

Je crois avoir appris cette chanson avec les mots « ... Il y a longtemps que je t'aime ... », mais je suis quand même curieux du sens de « lui » dans la version de M. Gagnon.

Voici la page 2 du recueil:
[image: À la claire fontaine]

Comment: Ce ne sont pas des fautes de frappes, toutes les versions québécoises que j'ai trouvées reproduisent les mêmes paroles. À moins bien sûr qu'elles ne font que reproduire la version du livre de Gagnon (publié en 1908).

Comment: Je viens de tomber sur [cette page](http://www2.cndp.fr/actualites/question/musique/musique_2006-06.htm) avec l'historique de la chanson, vu l'ancienneté et les différentes variante je pense de plus pour une erreur de transcription au départ de cette version québécoise.

Comment: Vraiment intéressant. Il y a un flou sur l'[origine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%80_la_claire_fontaine). [Eva Gauthier](http://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/fra/decouvrez/films-videos-enregistrements-sonores/gramophone-virtuel/Pages/eva-gauthier-bio.aspx) l'a chantée en 1917 ([LOC](http://www.loc.gov/jukebox/recordings/detail/id/5404/), [Coll. Can.](http://www.collectionscanada.gc.ca/obj/m2/f7/10326.mp3)) ainsi que le [_Trio Lyrique_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trio_lyrique) en [1948](https://youtu.be/3mz2PjhbpMs). Il est pas mal clair qu'ils disent _lui_...

Comment: @AgentBaptiste Ne peut-on envisager une version très ancienne où les paroles auraient été *lui y a longtemps que je **l**'aime jamais je ne **l**'oublierai*, etc... et les paroles ont été modifiées oralement et de façon imparfaite.

Comment: @Laure J'aime bien ton hypothèse. J'ai trouvé cet article de J. Gilliéron, [« La Claire Fontaine, chanson populaire française. Examen critique de diverses versions de cette chanson. »](http://www.persee.fr/doc/roma_0035-8029_1883_num_12_46_6264). À la page 327 on trouve diverses versions du refrain et l'auteur écrit que
"Les trois versions du Canada ont le même refrain ; comme on ne le
retrouve pas dans les versions européennes, il est permis de croire qu'il
est d'origine canadienne."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cette chanson traditionnelle a une longue histoire. D'origine française (probablement Normande), cette chanson a été introduite au Québec par les troupes de Montcalm  avant que les Québécois la renvoient en France comme une de leur chansons traditionnelles. Elle était donc connue en France peut-être dès le XV<sup>e</sup> siècle. <sup>1</sup> <sup>2</sup>

Parmi les nombreuses versions des paroles de cette chanson, les deux les plus connues sont, d'une part une connue uniquement au Québec : [celle figurant dans le recueil  *Chansons populaires du Canada*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=794-AAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:%22Ernest+Gagnon%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJl-3yzpDVAhVKLVAKHbqeD6wQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q&f=false) d'Ernest Gagnon publié (1<sup>er</sup>  édition 1865), et [l'autre](https://www.paroles.net/chansons-enfantines/paroles-a-la-claire-fontaine) plus universellement connue, que l'ont fait souvent chanter aux enfants.<sup>3</sup>

Les différences notoires entre ces deux versions :

- Il y a longtemps que je t'aime → Lui ya longtemps que je t'aime
- Moi je l'ai à pleurer → Moi je l'ai-t-à pleurer

peuvent s'expliquer par la transmission orale et les diverses versions qui se sont succédé et qu'on peut encore trouver de nos jours.<sup>4</sup>

Dans [un article](http://www.persee.fr/doc/roma_0035-8029_1883_num_12_46_6264)<sup>5</sup>  publié en 1883 dans la [revue Romania](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romania_(revue)) nous pouvons lire qu'une des versions canadiennes comportait dans le refrain :

> Il y a longtemps que je l'aime
>   Jamais je ne l'oublierai

L'emploi du pronom tonique *lui* pour mettre l'emphase sur le pronom complément (*l'*) est habituel et ne choque pas. Ernest Gagnon a mélangé deux versions de tradition orale dans son recueil qui s'est avéré populaire, et sa version s'est en quelque sorte popularisée. Il est vrai que dans les chansons populaires, la logique n'est pas toujours cherchée. Donc nous sommes bien en présence d'une tradition québécoise mais pas d'une tournure dont l'emploi est répandue au-delà de cette chanson.

Cet article par contre ne signale aucune variante sur *Moi je l'ai-t-à pleurer*. On pourrait supposer que ceci ne se retrouve que dans la version d'Ernest Gagnon. D'ailleurs cette fausse liaison choque-t-elle vraiment? Peut-être pas si on se met dans le contexte d'une chanson populaire de tradition orale et de surcroît dans une version mise à l'écrit à une époque où la majorité des gens ne savaient ni lire ni écrire.

J'ai entendu cette [version chantée](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdrOBDYMSUw) par Rob McLaren (Canadien) où on entend une autre liaison surprenante :

> sur la plus ‿ haute branche

Ce qui bien sûr ne saurait se rendre à l'écrit.

<sup>1</sup><sub>[Aux origines de « À la claire fontaine »](http://www2.cndp.fr/actualites/question/musique/musique_2006-06.htm) (Attention ce texte comporte au moins une faute de frappe, lire :

La version notée ici (voir la première partition en sol ou en mi b du CD) est très probablement originaire de Normandie ; pourtant, c’est par le biais du Québec que la chanson nous est revenue sous cette forme. Ayant traversé l’Atlantique, vers le milieu du **XVIII**<sup>e</sup> siècle (*au lieu de XIII*, avec les soldats de Montcalm – ce qui explique le rythme de marche sur lequel elle est souvent chantée –, elle servit de chant national aux patriotes franco-canadiens lors de la grande révolte de 1837 contre l’hégémonie anglaise.  En effet Montcalm est arrivé dans l'actuel Québec en 1756.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>[À la claire fontaine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%80_la_claire_fontaine)</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>Même si ce n'est pas une chanson pour enfants, comme le montre des études à ce sujet. Voir par exemple [l'article de Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%80_la_claire_fontaine#Sens_cach.C3.A9).</sub>

<sup>4</sup> <sub>En voir quelques unes [ici](https://www.culture-libre.org/wiki/A_la_claire_fontaine).</sub>

<sup>5</sup><sub>Gilliéron J. La Claire Fontaine, chanson populaire française. Examen critique de diverses versions de cette chanson. In: Romania, tome 12 n°46-47, 1883. pp. 307-331.

Merci à @RyanKavanagh de l'avoir signalé</sub>

---